# React Router give blank page

Tags: reactjs, router

I Try this code to companion tow composts in react using routs but it render blank page

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes , Route } from 'react-router-dom';
// import * as BooksAPI from './BooksAPI'
import './App.css';
import SearchBook from './components/SearchBook';
import Main from './components/Main';


class BooksApp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showSearchPage: false
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Root">
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Main />} />
          <Route path="/search" element = {<SearchBook />}/>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default BooksApp
```

when i tried to render the components directly like this

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Main />
        <SearchBook />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

it worked fine

Comment: Share your App.js file code also.. So that,  we will get a clear idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to configure all the routes inside the App.js. If your are providing routes inside `BooksApp` component. Please make sure, you have imported and called the `BooksApp` component in the App.js.

You need to import BrowserRouter and wrap all routes inside the BrowserRouter as like given below,

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes , Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
// import * as BooksAPI from './BooksAPI'
import './App.css';
import SearchBook from './components/SearchBook';
import Main from './components/Main';


class BooksApp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showSearchPage: false
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Root">
       <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Main />} />
          <Route path="/search" element = {<SearchBook />}/>
        </Routes>
       </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default BooksApp
```